# Eisenstein's Lemma

Tags: number-theory, legendre-symbol

Hi I've read the proof here.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_Lemma

On the line about division it says

$$k a = p \times \left \lfloor {\dfrac {k a} p} \right \rfloor + r$$
where $r\in S′$.

Can someone explain why $r\in S′$?

Thanks

Comment: Because of the division theorem.

Comment: Sorry I'm still confused. Division theorem implies that r is unique why is r necessarily in S'?

Comment: The division algorithm also says that the remainder $r$ is "smaller", which means here that it is in $S'$. Because it is modulo $p$, the division algorithm gives that we can take $r$ in the set of least positive residues.

Comment: Thanks! That cleared things up.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the division algorithm as shown in the comments.